# How to run .sh script form Django view?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell, django-views

stack overflow.

I'm trying to run some simple bash script (.sh) from Django view.

My views.py:

```
def start_stop(request):
    subprocess.Popen(['/home/ubuntu/contacts/contacts/scripts/test.sh'], shell=True)
    result = 'Success'
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

My bash script test.sh:

```
echo "testing text"
source /home/ubuntu/contacts/ENV/bin/activate
cd /home/ubuntu/contacts/contacts/scripts/
python final_poster.py
```

My main goal is activate the virtualenv and start python script name "final_poster.py". But it doesn't work. I also tried to use subprocess.call without any success result. I am stuck on it, can you help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What is not working exactly? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @NahuelIanni .sh script don't run python script. I don't know exactly why.
Now i trying to use subprocess.call and getting return code 126, don't know what it mean.

Comment: @nikihub read my comment above.

Comment: Why can't you include the script in your project, import it, and call the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think if don't see any error on the shell, then the script is running properly. If you want to see python shell's output, then you can add [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to bash script. For example:

```
echo "testing text"
source /home/ubuntu/contacts/ENV/bin/activate
cd /home/ubuntu/contacts/contacts/scripts/
python final_poster.py >> logfile.log
```

Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673096/get-python-command-line-output-when-called-from-a-bash-script) for details.

Comment: I tried to do something similar with the `.sh` file having shebang `#!/bin/sh` which didn't work but `#!/bin/bash` did work.